# Comparar resultado de un SELECT count SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo una duda con un query en SQL que estoy realizando, tengo una consulta con un WHERE

```
WHERE (B.antiguo IS NULL OR B.estatus = '3' AND 
(SELECT COUNT(estatus) AS TOTAL FROM hisavisos F
WHERE F.antiguo = '2686D300-C081-485A-B8A6-F5A73835C9BD'
 AND F.estatus IN ('1', '2') HAVING COUNT(estatus) = 0)
```

Necesito que el resultado de ese SELECT Count compararlo, en ese WHERE, que solo sea valido el WHERE si el resultado de ese count sea mayor a 0, intento compararlo con un ">" pero me marca un error, de qué manera podria realizarlo?

```
WHERE (B.antiguo IS NULL OR B.estatus = '3' AND 
(SELECT COUNT(estatus) AS TOTAL FROM hisavisos F
WHERE F.antiguo = '2686D300-C081-485A-B8A6-F5A73835C9BD' 
AND F.estatus IN ('1', '2') HAVING COUNT(estatus) = 0) > 0)
```

Intente realizarlo de esta manera, que sea valida la condicion en el WHERE si el resultado de ese count es mayor a 0, pero me marca un error de sintaxis

Comment: Esa condición siempre será falsa porque el HAVING hace que siempre regrese cero y luego comparas para que sea mayor que cero.

Answer (score 0):

En teoría debería funcionar simplemente tomando todo el paréntesis que tiene la subconsulta como un número.

```
WHERE (B.antiguo IS NULL OR B.estatus = '3' AND 
(SELECT COUNT(estatus) AS TOTAL FROM hisavisos F
WHERE F.antiguo = '2686D300-C081-485A-B8A6-F5A73835C9BD' 
AND F.estatus IN ('1', '2') HAVING COUNT(estatus) = 0) > 0
```

Pero lo que está definitivamente mal es la cláusula HAVING ya que condiciona directamente lo mismo que se supone que querés calcular. Es decir, el COUNT de estatus. Entonces lo que deberías escribir es más bien...

```
WHERE (B.antiguo IS NULL OR B.estatus = '3' AND 
(SELECT COUNT(estatus) AS TOTAL FROM hisavisos F
WHERE F.antiguo = '2686D300-C081-485A-B8A6-F5A73835C9BD' 
AND F.estatus IN ('1', '2')) > 0
```

Dicho esto, y si es que funciona, vale remarcar que esta consulta con un ID fijo no debería terminar en código de una aplicación.